# RSpec should be_true vs should == true

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there any difference at all between:

```
something.should == true
```

and

```
something.should be_true
```

?

Comment: there is a difference depending on the context of usage, check my answer below

Comment: http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2014/01/17/2674/rspec-be-true-be_true-are-different

Comment: @feed_me_code there is no cause for argument, I wanted to just clarify and contribute to knowledge and not engage in an argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is: `expect(something).to be_true` however there is no difference when used properly. Expecting something to `== true` should only be evaluated against expressions.

- See docs: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#truthiness

**Rspec Tests:**

```
describe "is the equation true? " do
  let!(:add) { 5+5 == 10 }

  it "be_true" do
    add.should be_true #passes
  end

  it "expect be_true" do
    expect(add).to be_true #passes
  end

  it "== true" do
    add.should == true #passes
  end
end
```

**Update for strings:**

A string is not `== true` so it will fail, but it will pass as `be_true` because anything except for `false` or `nil` is considered `truthy`. **However, this is NOT how you check for a `string`.**

**See this example** for how to properly check for a value in a `string`:

```
str = "happy dance!"
```

For finding if *text* is in a `string`, you would use: `expect(str).to include("happy dance!")`

Comment: Just for posterity: `expect(something).to be_true` is considered the newer, better way to write the specs. The `expect` syntax accomplishes the same thing but does not rely on monkey patching all objects to have the `should` method, which on rare occasions can cause problems. Although rspec stills supports both ways.

Comment: The answer is not correct, there is a difference as I have stated in my answer below

Comment: @feed_me_code I have give a case of where `something.should == true` and `something.should be_true` are not same, to make this clearer is why `be_truthy` and `be_falsy` is being added to more recent versions of rspec

Comment: @feed_me_code do undownvote my answer as it is a clear context for showing the difference, and it does not require a downvote

Comment: to prove to you, see a blogpost on same topic: http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2014/01/17/2674/rspec-be-true-be_true-are-different

Comment: @feed_me_code in Ruby everything evaluates to `true` except `nil` or `false` that is `truthiness`, unlike in statically typed languages e.g Java a boolean method in ruby can return a string or any object order than `nil` or `false` as true, yet that boolean method would pass `should be_true` but might fail `should == true`, `should == ` is a test of equality and not a test of `truthiness`, I hope this clarifies as I would stop making further comments on this. Thanks once again

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the whole notion of "used correctly" doesn't really apply.  `be_true` and `== true` behave differently. That's the bottom line.  The fact that they return the same result for _some_ values is not really relevant. And as noted elsewhere, RSpec has changed the name of `be_true` to `be_truthy` so as to avoid misleading users.

Answer (score 0):

The answer supplied to this question is wrong as the below depicts, the first test is a test of equality while the second is a test of truthiness, the first would fail because `something != true` while the later would pass because anything order than `nil` or `false` is `truthy` in ruby

```
require 'rspec'

describe "do something" do

  let(:something) { "hey" }
  it { something.should == true }
  it { something.should be_true }
end
```

Comment: the down voter should not be shy to explain why he down voted

Answer (score -3):

*No, there is no difference.*

The latter is syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong, as noted in my comment on the accepted answer.